# Wrap too long string output with new lines in bash

Tags: bash

Imagine your script outputs some real strange output like:

```
fdjsagnfafeowkagfdsngodagfoeagnfiosnthoaogjerapogrjeagnfdosngtnsrhig ofskhnIAGNRIEAGPREAOGJRIAEGRNIEOASGNFAIGRNESUIGRIOAEGRNIAENGRUEAOREANFDOIGNRUESIGORNAEIGNREIOAGRIUESGRJOEAGRNEOSIGRNEPAGRJAEIO
```

Crap I know. Probably it would look better this way:

```
fdjsagnfafeowkagfdsngodagfoeagnfiosnthoaogjera
pogrjeagnfdosngtnsrhig ofskhnIAGNRIEAGPREAOGJR
IAEGRNIEOASGNFAIGRNESUIGRIOAEGRNIAENGRUEAOREAN
FDOIGNRUESIGORNAEIGNREIOAGRIUESGRJOEAGRNEOSIGR
NEPAGRJAEIO
```

I am trying to do this with base64 encoded string data in bash. How could I do it?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20065991/797495

Comment: You should be able to store the output as a variable and then try something like: `echo $varname | base64`

Comment: I am not using java nor wrapping the output for parsing. I am wraping it because it would get lost if I didn't. The data is being sent over networks and it's all nastily complicated.

Comment: @ryekayo I know how to make base64 data. I just need to print it wrapped as in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your sample input, `fold` will produce the output that you request.  Suppose that we have this file:

```
$ cat longline
fdjsagnfafeowkagfdsngodagfoeagnfiosnthoaogjerapogrjeagnfdosngtnsrhig ofskhnIAGNRIEAGPREAOGJRIAEGRNIEOASGNFAIGRNESUIGRIOAEGRNIAENGRUEAOREANFDOIGNRUESIGORNAEIGNREIOAGRIUESGRJOEAGRNEOSIGRNEPAGRJAEIO
```

To make lines with width 46-characters:

```
$ fold -w 46 longline
fdjsagnfafeowkagfdsngodagfoeagnfiosnthoaogjera
pogrjeagnfdosngtnsrhig ofskhnIAGNRIEAGPREAOGJR
IAEGRNIEOASGNFAIGRNESUIGRIOAEGRNIAENGRUEAOREAN
FDOIGNRUESIGORNAEIGNREIOAGRIUESGRJOEAGRNEOSIGR
NEPAGRJAEIO
```

If you want to use it in a pipeline, `fold` also accepts stdin:

```
$ fold -w 46 <longline
fdjsagnfafeowkagfdsngodagfoeagnfiosnthoaogjera
pogrjeagnfdosngtnsrhig ofskhnIAGNRIEAGPREAOGJR
IAEGRNIEOASGNFAIGRNESUIGRIOAEGRNIAENGRUEAOREAN
FDOIGNRUESIGORNAEIGNREIOAGRIUESGRJOEAGRNEOSIGR
NEPAGRJAEIO
```

On Linux, `fold` is part of [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/fold-invocation.html) and should be installed by default.  It is also available under [Mac OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/fold.1.html).

Comment: Well, would you have guessed, there's no way to not count escape codes... :-/