# How to download data client-side with mobile Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, download, mobile-safari

I know there's a lot of questions already existing on SO related to this kind of problem, for instance:

- [Create a file in memory for user to download, not through server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server)
- [Using HTML5/Javascript to generate and save a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file)
- [Data protocol URL size limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695151/data-protocol-url-size-limitations)
- [Save file Javascript with file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717851/save-file-javascript-with-file-name)
- [Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)
- [Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578530/failed-to-execute-atob-on-window)

This question is very specific to Safari on iOS 8.1.3 (Mobile, iPad 2+).  We have an offline *AngularJS* web app using *Application Cache* and *IndexedDB* to store data.  One kind of data is PDF documents that can be relatively large: about 25 megabytes max.  We are storing these files in *IndexedDB* and when the user wants to download it, we have this file in-memory within the browser with JavaScript.

The problem is really when the user wants to save it.  Safari Mobile crashes maybe from a size limitation of Data URI or something else.

```
this.save = function (file) {
    var mediaType = "application/pdf";

    var link = document.createElement("a");
    var blob = new Blob([this.fromBase64ToBinary(file.content)], { type: mediaType });

    var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.download = file.name;
    link.href = blobUrl;
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
};
```

In a service, we have a function `save(file)` where `file` is an object containing two properties:

1. `name`: the filename;
2. `content`: data of the file, which is base 64 encoded, then we transform it to binary.

The `atob()` function can be the cause?  When I do a step-by-step debugging on the iPad running this code, it crashes right there (ie: line with `var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);`).

```
this.fromBase64ToBinary = function (base64) {
    var byteCharacters = atob(base64);
    var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
};
```

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277051/what-alternative-for-atob-on-ios) and [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37277200/4545506). Because `atob` in ios crashes when a space character exists.

Comment: Why you need to use base64? I'm asking because when you use, the file becomes 37% bigger. 

It will be approximately 37% larger:

Very roughly, the final size of Base64-encoded binary data is equal to 1.37 times the original data size
Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: I have one question, does it break for all file sizes or specific file sizes?

Comment: as per comment by @ykaragol, would a base64 encoded string have a space in it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092019/can-a-base64-encoded-string-contain-whitespace

Comment: @Marco the answer to your question is in the comment by ykaragol

Answer (score 1):

I dealt with a similar issue. The way I solved it was this:

```
// Detects if Safari 9 or less
var isSafariNineOrLess = navigator.vendor && navigator.vendor.indexOf('Apple') 
> -1 &&
navigator.userAgent &&
navigator.userAgent.indexOf('CriOS') === -1 &&
navigator.userAgent.indexOf('FxiOS') === -1 &&
window.ApplePaySession === undefined;

...

if(!isSafariNineOrLess) {
    save(file);
}
else {
   var myLink = document.getElementById('myLink');
       if(myLink) {
          myLink.removeAttribute('href');
          myLink.setAttribute('href', 'http://example.com/download.pdf.zip');
        }
 }
```

Then when people click on the link they can download a zipped file that contains the PDF. You look like you are using https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js, or something similar, and that absolutely does not work with Safari 9 and below.

Take a look at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio-mac/?sku=communitymac&rel=16# in Safari 9 or below for the behavior I'm talking about, where the **a** tag **href** is changed to a URL to download a file.

Let me know if this works for you!