# What alternative for atob on ios?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

In my Ionic application I use the atob() command.

It works fine on chrome & android, but for some reason it does not work on iOS, is there an alternative?

Comment: Afaik iOS 7+ supports `atob`. If you are targeting devices with older OS you might consider to write include a polyfill https://github.com/davidchambers/Base64.js/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IOS, `atob` does not accept space characters.
So use `atob` like that:

```
var input = response.data.content;
input = input.replace(/\s/g, '');
var content = window.atob(input);
```

Have a look at that answer about [`atob`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30106551/4545506)