# EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: InvalidCharacterError: DOM Exception 5

Tags: ios, ionic2

I am using camera plugin in my IOS ionic 2 app. i am getting this error when take a picture using camera. It works fine in android. Could anyone help me how to fix this issue?

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: InvalidCharacterError: DOM
>   Exception 5 atob@[native code]
>   dataURItoBlob@file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/E8901626-292D-421E-AFEC-2FC49AC14587/

Comment: Well, this usually comes when image is not encoded properly!

Comment: Could you help me How to fix it ?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277051/what-alternative-for-atob-on-ios)

Comment: @ykaragol, Okay Thank you. Will try